# How compare .csv files or Strings and find similarity?

Tags: java, string, csv, data-structures, try-catch

I've been given a .csv file with comma separated values. They are listed as, `"2016-03-23,106.129997,25703500"` in order of `"date,price,volume"`. The parameters already have a preset value that will be determined by a program which will verify the code. When the program inputs a random date such as: `"2016-03-23"`. The code should output the location in the .csv file where it is equal to the date. When the code finds a date that is equal to the input it should return only the second column of that row which is price as a double.

The steps I've taken thus far is:

**1.** Read the parameter which contains the .csv file. Compare the first column of the .csv file with the date parameter and check for equality. (.eqauls). Though I know if this code were to be generated it will return back the entire .csv file.

**2.** Assume the Parameter which contains a string is also a .csv file and compare them as if it were by column. Though that just recreates the first problem and I'm not sure how to read two .csv files.

**The question:**

> I need to return a double. Though my code sets any declaration of values out of scope. And when trying to convert it: *"The method `parseDouble(String)` in the type Double is not applicable for the arguments `(String[])`"*
>
> How can a pinpoint a specific part in a .csv file not just column, but row as well. If [1] and alike determine the column what is used to determine a row?

```
public static double getPrice(String stockFileName, String date) {

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(stockFileName));
        String line = "";
        String unparsedFile = "";
        Double Price;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {}
        br.close();

        String[] Ans = unparsedFile.split(",");
        for (String item: Ans) {
            if (Ans[1].equals(date)) {
                double aDouble = Double.parseDouble(Ans);
                return Ans;

            }
        }
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }

}
```

**What I think should be done:**

> Create a for loop that will generate each row of the .csv file. Convert each row to a string value of an array and have the code check each row by itself (to not generate the entire column) whether it is equal to the date. Once the row is determined return back [2] of that row which is price.
>
> Though, if the parameter is set as `String stockFileName` already; should it be I check whether [1] of a line in the String is equal to date? If so simply return [2] of that line?

Answer (score 0):

Use a java library to parse csv file 
(that way you don't have to reinvent the wheel). 
Check this jar file out **https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencsv/**

Once you have the jar in your classpath, 
you can loop through each line of your CSV file 
as follows and look for a match on column that 
has date and use the column with price for the matching line.

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"));
String [] nextLine;
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
    System.out.println(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + "etc...");
}
```

Comment: We're not allowed to use libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue may be that you are reading all of the lines of the stock file but not actually doing anything with them because your while loop is empty.  If you need the row number just keep a counter, if you need the whole row it will be in variable line just before the return if you need to do anything with  it

```
public static double  getPrice(String stockFileName, String date) {

  try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(stockFileName));
    String line = "";
    String unparsedFile = "";
    Double Price;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      String[] Ans = line.split(",");
      for (String item : Ans){ 
        if(Ans[1].equals(date)){
          double aDouble = Double.parseDouble(Ans[2]);    
          return aDouble;
        }
      }
    }
    br.close();

  } catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("Error"); 
  }
  return null;
}
```